# Import CSV into Google Sheets with local variable in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, gspread

My program downloads a csv from an ftp server, makes modifications to formatting, then I'm currently stuck trying to upload it to the google sheets. I have it working when I select a local file....

Currently when I use the writer variable it says `TypeError: '_csv.writer' object is not iterable`

```
with open('test5.csv', 'w') as f:
    # Overwrite the old file with the modified rows
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(new_rows)**

    print("done!")
    print(str(writer))


gc = gspread.service_account(
    filename='xxx.json')
print("Connected TO GOOGLE")
**gc.import_csv("my-sheet-id", writer)**
print("UPLOADED")
```

I believe that gspread is looking for a csv file and won't accept variables? Can I use the writer to write a csv file to a local variable instead of to my p? I ask this as I'm looking to make this server sided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing in `writer` here:

```
gc.import_csv("my-sheet-id", writer)
```

don't you mean to pass in 'test5.csv'?

As a side note, it's pretty confusing when you have random stars in your code. You should remove those before posting to SO.

Comment: Sorry. Yes I can pass in the file it just created. But I want it to pass in *BEFORE* it writes to pc locally. So that way I can host this on a server

Comment: @A.House Right, then use the something like tempfile https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html